# Inserir seta em um input submit para quando o jsf renderizar apareça no botão

Tags: html5, css3, jsf, jsf-2.2

Fiz um layout todo em *HTML5* e tenho um botão "próximo" onde possuo uma seta no mesmo, porém os desenvolvedores estão fazendo ela em *JSF* e ao renderizar o *commandButton* vira um `input type submit` e a seta não aparece mais.
Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer para a seta aparecer no input `submit`?

Onde o `button` está implementado:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2">
  <div class="bigButton blueButton buttons">
    <button class="fullFormWidth" onclick="location.href='proxima.html'">
      <div class="rightWhiteCarret"></div>
      Próximo
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nessa `div` que está a seta, eu a fiz modelando bordas sem inserir imagem.

```
<div class="rightWhiteCarret"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Peça para eles inserirem a sua div dentro da tag commandButton, vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
<h:commandButton styleClass="fullFormWidth" onclick="location.href='proxima.html'">
    <div class="rightWhiteCarret"></div>
    Próximo
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: posso tentar isso, mas o que fiz foi crar uma div separada onde esta a seta e setei no css para display: relative e movi pelas margens para que fique em cima do botão no lugar devido.